# iPhone viewport meta tag width=device-width not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, viewport, meta-tags

I tried all possible viewport meta tags but nothing seems to be working.
Can anyone help me on this?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale = 1.0">
```

Site is http://sival.dk/ . You can run on chrome iphone simulator. When you load the page you feel that the page is fit, but try scrolling through x position, you could see that the page is not fitted entirely in iphone

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Cory's answer. I finally found that the problem was not with meta tag, seems the problem was with the title involved in the page. See Marked answer for reference.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this, I usually use the chrome developer tools to look for any element whose padding or margin is making the page wider than the device width. In this case, it was your `<h1 class="site-title">sival</h1>`. See the screenshot below. Adding `margin: 0` to the styles for that element (or fixing the element in another way) should solve your problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This image is not set to device-width cause the problem within your media queries.

```
  <img src="http://sival.dk/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Logo.png" width="450" height="168">
```

and this heading tag margin needed to be set.

```
<h1 class="site-title">sival</h1>
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer mate. It works since Cory replied b4 u, marking his answer :)